# populating a nested list with items from 2 other nested lists | python

Tags: python, list, indexing, iterator, iteration

EDITED

I have 2 nested lists, example:

```
cluster_list_all_thermostat_starts = [[0, 1000, 1200, 1500, 7000], [2,300,400],[4,500,765,100,2500,3000]]

list_all_thermostat_set_points = [[20, 20, 20.5, 19.5, 19], [20,23.5,19.5],[20,20,19.5,20,25,21.5]]
```

They have exact shapes, meaning: lists in given index in both master lists have the same number of elements.

I want to create a nested "master list" in which all lists will have the same number of elements and the elements will be filled from the list_of_start_times and list_of_temperatures:

`master_list =[[temperature,temperature,temperature,...,temperature],
               [temperature,temperature,temperature,...,temperature],
               [temperature,temperature,temperature,...,temperature]]`

`master_list` should have 3 lists, each one having the same number of elements.

I do it this way now:

```
master_list_of_quartiles = []
for domek in range(len(list_of_start_times)):

master_list = [0]*24*365*4
temperatures = list_all_thermostat_set_points[domek]

house_list_start_charge = cluster_list_all_thermostat_starts[domek]
house_list_end_charge = cluster_list_all_thermostat_starts[domek] #the same list is used because the thermostat only has start times
#print(house_list_start_charge)


for kwadrans in range(len(house_list_start_charge)):
    print(kwadrans)
    start_charge = int(house_list_start_charge[kwadrans])
    print(start_charge)
    try:
        end_charge = int(house_list_end_charge[kwadrans+1]) - 1
    except IndexError:
        end_charge = 4*24*365   
    print(end_charge)
    this_temp = temperatures[kwadrans]
    print(this_temp)

    for j in range(start_charge , end_charge):
        master_list[j]=this_temp
    master_list_of_quartiles.append(master_list)
```

All: `print(start_charge), print(this_temp), print(end_charge)` show good values, but filling out the master_list doesn't work as it fills it with the last iterated item.

The goal is to transform `master_list_of_quartiles` later into a dataframe of 3 columns and 24*365*4 indexes.

**How to fix it while keeping proper indexing?**

Comment: not sure where 80 comes from with your example input.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem!

```
for domek in range(len(house_has_thermostat)):

master_list = []
temperatures = list_all_thermostat_set_points[domek]

house_list_start_charge = cluster_list_all_thermostat_starts[domek]
house_list_end_charge = cluster_list_all_thermostat_starts[domek] #the same list is used because the thermostat only has start times


for kwadrans in range(len(house_list_start_charge)):
    print(kwadrans)
    start_charge = int(house_list_start_charge[kwadrans])
    print(start_charge)
    try:
        end_charge = int(house_list_end_charge[kwadrans+1]) - 1
    except IndexError:
        end_charge = 4*24*365   
    print(end_charge)
    this_temp = temperatures[kwadrans]
    print(this_temp)


    for j in range(start_charge , end_charge):
        master_list.extend([this_temp])
while len(master_list)<4*24*365:
    master_list.extend([this_temp])
master_list_of_quartiles.append(master_list)
```